# How to simulate the AppStore update process on device/simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, upgrade

We have submitted an update version of our existing applications in the App Store recently. But we have received a issue from one of the users, saying that the app is not functioning properly after the update. So in order to replicate the same, what are the steps to reproduce, so that i can analyse the issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simulate this **before** pushing yoru updated version to the AppStore you can:

1. Download the old version of your app from the appstore
2. Run the updated version of your app from XCode on the same device.

What will happen behind the scenes is that your app will be updated in a way similar to the Appstore. Your app will be partially updated while your doucments folder will stay the same.  (what usually causes problems)

This solution is better because it lets you check for problems **before** and update was pushed to the Appstore.

Comment: The problem is already the updated version is existing in the App Store :(

Comment: My solution still stands for future updates. Tell the user to delete the app and reinstall it. If the problem still exists there's a good chance the problem isn't related to the updating process but to the code itself.

Comment: Does the os re-lauches the application once the update is done?

Comment: And more over what about UserDefults? will those be retained even after app got updated?Kindly let me know as i am not aware of this process. thanks in adv :)

Comment: The app won't re-launch but it will save the `NSUserDefaults` after an update. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: So does it mean that if you save some data using UserDefults and then update the application, The old data will be retained?

Comment: If possible, Can i get the documentation of the app update mechanism and what exactly happens behind the scenes? kindly lemme know if you know any?

Comment: The old data will be kept in the app as long as the user didn't deleted the app. I don't think there is documentation for this specific case but you can test it your self and see that the values are kept in the app after an update.

Answer (score 0):

All that is required is to have the version of the app that is in the app store on your device, then install the updated version to your device. You can debug it using Xcode when you install the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I get this a lot. The solution is a bit annoying, but you need to keep a history of IPAs you've submitted so you can put the on your phone through iTunes (so not the simulator) and then, run your code on your device putting a breakpoint on your applicationDidFinishLaunching handler in your app delegate, and start tracing from there. You should be able to find the old app store version in your organiser from the last time you submitted, or, go through your SVN/GIT history and checkout the version tagged to your release version.

Answer (score 0):

Many times in the past that has happened to me where I test a new revision and everything looks fine but when I submit an update and is approved, users start complaining about a crash or lost data.

This is way I approach the problem.

1. (This is most important step) You need to either have your old code or old binary installed on your actual apple device. (Physical iPhone / iPad)
2. Now go to iTunes and install your new update.
3. Attach your physical iPhone / iPad to you computer, Launch Xcode and start debugging it.

NOTE: There have been many times when things work perfectly in the Simulator but break on the actual device. Its always important to test your code on the real thing as that is what the users are going to be on.

Comment: I prefer checking for bugs and glitches in a new version **before** I send the update to apple. Check my answer.